# Difference between forEachOrdered() and sequential() methods of Java 8?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I am working on java 8 parallel stream and wanting to print the elements in parallel stream is some order (say insertion order, reverse order or sequential order).

For which i tried the following code:

```
        System.out.println("With forEachOrdered:");
        listOfIntegers
            .parallelStream()
            .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("With Sequential:");
        listOfIntegers.parallelStream()
                    .sequential()
                    .forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
```

And for both of these, i got the same output as follows:

```
With forEachOrdered:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
With Sequential:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

from the api documentation, i can see that:

> forEachOrdered ->  This is a terminal operation.

and

> sequential  -> This is an intermediate operation.

So my question is which one is more better to use?
and in which scenarios, one should be preferred over other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`listOfIntegers.parallelStream().sequential().forEach()` creates a parallel `Stream` and then converts it to a sequential `Stream`, so you might as well use `listOfIntegers.stream().forEach()` instead, and get a sequential `Stream` in the first place.

`listOfIntegers.parallelStream().forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.print(e + " "))` performs the operation on a parallel `Stream`, but guarantees the elements will be consumed in the encounter order of the `Stream` (if the `Stream` has a defined encounter order). However, it can be executed on multiple threads.

I don't see a reason of ever using `listOfIntegers.parallelStream().sequential()`. If you want a sequential `Stream`, why create a parallel `Stream` first?

Comment: because you may want to have some heavy operations done in parallel, and then re-sequence the stream for final output

Comment: @AdrianShum I'm not sure how well that will work in terms of performance, since the stream is evaluated lazily. It won't perform the first intermediate steps in parallel for all elements and then proceed with the rest of the intermediate steps and terminal operation on a sequential stream. Only when you reach the terminal operation, it starts performing the intermediate operations on individual elements until they become inputs of the terminal operation.

Comment: That's true.  Maybe then it is only useful for cases that I am writing some util that will work on a provided stream, and I want to make sure it is sequential even if the user is providing a parallel one?

Comment: @AdrianShum yes, if you didn't create the stream yourself, and require it to be sequential, that would be a good use of `sequential()`.

Comment: Consider `list.parallelStream().sorted().forEachOrdered(…)` as a practical example that does heavy work in parallel but an ordered terminal operation.

Comment: @Holger but you don't convert the stream back to sequential stream in your example

Comment: Exactly. It’s an example of an operation where `.parallelStream(). … .forEachOrdered(…)` and `.parallelStream(). … sequential().forEach(…)` exhibit a noticeable difference. As you said, “the stream is evaluated lazily”, so if the terminal operation blocks the worker threads due to ordering constraints, you don’t get much parallelism unless you have a stateful intermediate operation like `sorted()`.

Answer (score 4):

You are asking somehow a misleading question, first you ask about:

```
 .parallelStream()
 .forEachOrdered(...)
```

This will *create a parallel* Stream, but elements will be consumed *in order*. If you add a `map` operation like this:

```
.map(...)
.parallelStream()
.forEachOrdered(...)
```

This will make the `map` very limited (from a parallel processing point of view) operations since threads have to wait for all other elements in encounter order to be processed (consumed by `forEachOrdered`). This regards stateless operations.

On the other hand if you have a *stateful operation* like:

```
.parallelStream()
.map()
.sorted()
.// other operations
```

Since `sorted` is stateful, the benefit of the stateless operations *before it* from a parallel processing will be bigger. And that happens because `sorted` has to gather all elements from the Stream, and Threads don't have to "wait" (at the `forEachOrdered`) for the elements in encounter order.

For the second example:

```
listOfIntegers.parallelStream()
                .sequential()
                .forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "))
```

you are basically saying turn parallel on and then turn it off. Streams are driven by the terminal operation, so even if you do:

```
 .map...
 .filter...
 .parallel()
 .map...
 .sequential
```

This means that the entire pipeline will be executed sequentially, not that some part will be parallel and the other sequential. You are also relying on the fact that `forEach` preserves order and may be at the moment it does, but may be in a later release, sine you said you don't care about order (by using `forEach` in the first place), there will be an internal shuffling of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

Stream pipelines may execute either sequentially or in parallel. This execution mode is a property of the stream. Streams are created with an initial choice of sequential or parallel execution. For example, `Collection.stream()` creates a sequential stream, and `Collection.parallelStream()` creates a parallel one.  This choice of execution mode may be modified by the `BaseStream.sequential()` or `BaseStream.parallel()` methods.

So there is no need to use:

```
listOfIntegers.parallelStream().sequential()
```

You can only use:

```
listOfIntegers.stream()
```

If you are creating a `parallel stream`, it is possible for the elements of the stream to be processed by different threads. The difference between `forEach` and `forEachOrdered` is that forEach will allow any element of a parallel stream to be processed in any order, while forEachOrdered will always process the elements of a parallel stream in the order of their appearance in the original stream. When using `parallelStream()` and `forEachOrdered` is a very good example on how you can take advantage of multiple cores and still preserve the order of the output. Note that forEachOrdered forces the iteration of the elements of the stream in an ordered fashion. However, any operation that is chained before forEachOrdered will still happen in parallel because the stream is a parallel stream.

It is not documented by Oracle exactly what happens when you change the stream execution mode multiple times in a pipeline. It is not clear whether it is the last change that matters or whether operations invoked after calling `parallel()` can be executed in parallel and operations invoked after calling `sequential()` will be executed sequentially.

Comment: "It is not documented exactly what happens when you change the stream execution mode multiple times in a pipeline". I disagree, it's spelled out clearly in the class documentation for [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) "Stream pipelines may execute *either* sequentially or in parallel"

Comment: @AnlonBurke Please read through the final what is not documented by Oracle.

Comment: The entire pipeline is *either* executed sequentially *or* in parallel. IMHO, that's what this sentence from the Javadoc says. It's not possible that some part will be `parallel` and some other other part `sequential` (in fact, that was tried for some time during the initial development of the Stream API, but has been given up because it was too complicated). I don't understand where your doubts about that come from.